# Mishkav/Mishkave... , Is there a difference?

Tags: arayot, mattos, parashas-kedoshim, parshat-acharei-mot

I am new to "Mi Yodeya?" and this is my first time asking questions.

First, I have always heard that everything that is written in the Torah has a purposeful meaning; nothing in it is a coincidence or a mistake - has veshalom! My question is, then, why is it written "mishkav zakhar" - 'mishkav' (singular) - and "mishkeve isha" - from 'mishkavim' (plural)? Do males have just one "mishkav" and females more than one?  Lastly, what is the meaning of 'mishkav/mishkavim'? I know that individually they mean 'lying/s (as on a bed), and bed/bedding.

I want to understand the phraseology of 'mishkav zakhar'. The only place I remember seeing it is in Numbers 31:17-18. I want to understand it so that I may better understand Lev. 18:22 and 20:13. Numbers 31:17-18 says: " ועתה הרגו כל זכר בטף, וכל אשה ידעת איש למשכב זכר הרגו. וכל הטף בנשים אשר לא ידעו משכב זכר החיו לכם."

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for this great question. Very astute!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase means literally "the lying of a man" and is euphemistic for intimate relations as performed by a man, which is how it is generally [translated](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.30-31?lang=bi) in the verses ([Numbers 31:17-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.30-31?lang=bi)) you cite:

> וְעַתָּ֕ה הִרְג֥וּ כָל־זָכָ֖ר בַּטָּ֑ף וְכָל־אִשָּׁ֗ה יֹדַ֥עַת אִ֛ישׁ לְמִשְׁכַּ֥ב זָכָ֖ר הֲרֹֽגוּ׃
>
> Now, therefore, slay every male among the children, and slay also every woman who has known a man carnally;
>
> וְכֹל֙ הַטַּ֣ף בַּנָּשִׁ֔ים אֲשֶׁ֥ר לֹא־יָדְע֖וּ מִשְׁכַּ֣ב זָכָ֑ר הַחֲי֖וּ לָכֶֽם׃
>
> but spare every young woman who has not had carnal relations with a man.

The converse phrase משכבי אשה is used to denote the ways one might lie with a woman (literally: the lyings of a woman) as in [Leviticus 18:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.22?lang=bi):

> וְאֶ֨ת־זָכָ֔ר לֹ֥א תִשְׁכַּ֖ב מִשְׁכְּבֵ֣י אִשָּׁ֑ה תּוֹעֵבָ֖ה הִֽוא׃
>
> Do not lie with a male as one lies with a woman; it is an abhorrence.

and [Leviticus 20:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.13?lang=bi):

> וְאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֨ר יִשְׁכַּ֤ב אֶת־זָכָר֙ מִשְׁכְּבֵ֣י אִשָּׁ֔ה תּוֹעֵבָ֥ה עָשׂ֖וּ שְׁנֵיהֶ֑ם מ֥וֹת יוּמָ֖תוּ דְּמֵיהֶ֥ם בָּֽם׃
>
> If a man lies with a male as one lies with a woman, the two of them have done an abhorrent thing; they shall be put to death—their blood is upon them.

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 54a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.54a.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) notes, as did you, the usage of the plural with regard to the lying of the woman and derives accordingly that there are two (anatomical) ways to lay with a woman:

> משכבי אשה מגיד לך הכתוב ששני משכבות באשה
>
> “the lyings of a woman” - The verse teaches you that there are two (anatomical) manners of lying with a woman.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is yes there is a very good reason, though sorry, it's somewhat graphic.

"Mishkevei isha" (plural) refers to vaginal and anal; only one of those applies to males. This is in fact the Talmud's source that the same punishment would apply, if a woman was a prohibited relation, for either type of activity.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No worries about the graphic nature of the content, after all, we are all adults here (I think).

Comment: @AdM - Do not be so sure. I am not an adult. :) Although I am old enough to not be immature and take halacha seriously.

Comment: Good to know. Someone help me understand this, then... I can see how 'mishkeve isha' would refer to a women's vagina and anus. I do not understand how mishkav zakhar would mean a man's anus. Because the Torah mentions in Numbers/Bamidbar 31:17-18: "...vekhol isha yoda`at ish lemishkav zakhar... banashim asher lo yade`u mishkav zakhar..."  How can a woman be intimate with that part of a man's body?  I believe then, that mishkav zakhar means a man's penis.

Comment: @Adm mishkav means penetrates zakhar means a man (a woman can not penetrate so no mishkav)

Comment: @hazoriz Thank you for your comment.  You said: "mishkav means penetrates zakhar means a man (a woman can not penetrate so no mishkav)".  What about mishkeve isha?  What does mishkeve mean in this case?

Comment: @AdM the **penetrations** of/to a woman (as said in the answers there are 2 of them) (2 ways a woman can be penetrated)

Comment: @ezra in Judaism is not an adult at 13(/12) years old (and no other age), i think almost everyone here is above 13/12

Comment: @AdM mishkav zahar means a man penetrates , mishkavai Isha means the penetrations of/to a woman,

Comment: @shalom which Torah passage did rabbinical authorities tend and/or tend not to use as a basis for allowing anal sex between a husband and wife? Is it one of the passages quoted here?

Comment: @hazoriz About the "2 ways a woman can be penetrated", is that a kosher sexual practice between a husband and wife?

Comment: @ninamag completely kosher although recommend to avoid (to be holly), but the ejaculation should be only vaginal, (there is an opinion that if not often even ejaculation would be kosher)